# ALIMENTAR TABELAS (SQL SERVER )

Tags: sql

Opa Bom dia.

Tenho um banco sql, neste banco existe uma tabela para Pessoas, é uma segunda tabela para cadastro de credenciais,  em uma terceira tabela e feito a associação da credencial com a pessoa, ou seja existe uma Tabela chamado CRED_PESSOAS, onde através do código da pessoa é numero da credencial é feita a associação da credencial para pessoa.

Tenho um cliente que pediu para alimentar essas informações de credencial através de scripts, já alimentei as duas tabelas (PESSOAS E CREDENCIAIS) minha duvida é como criar uma condição, onde eu pegue por exemplo a credencial X para pessoa Y, credencial y para pessoa x e assim em diante.

[image: Tabela que preciso Alimentar]
[image: Tabela de Pessoas com o código que preciso para alimentar a tabela CRED_PESSOA]

Desde já agradeço.
Gustavo Braga

Comment: Gustavo, bem vindo ao stackoverflow em português, seria legal fazer um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), e editar sua pergunta com algumas informações como;  Qual banco de dados? e qual a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: OPA, Obrigado pela dica vou me atentar mais sim, so que não não conheço muito do SQL é muito menos desta base acabei de receber esta demanda aqui no escritório, coisa de comercial que vende o que não pode entregar kkk

Comment: Bom, você esta fazendo o insert desses dados, acredito que saiba qual banco onde essas informações estão sendo armazenadas, e qual os campos das tabelas.

Comment: Então ainda não entendi o que precisa saber exatamente, o Banco é SQL SERVER, as tabelas que estou alimentando são aquelas que citei, na tabela credencial eu alimentei uma coluna chamada CRED_NUMERO, como o numero das credenciais, Na Tabela PESSOAS fiz num tipo de insert pois as pessoas já estavam cadastradas, dela so preciso pegar a PES_NUMERO para associar com com a credencial na tabela CRED_PESSOAS

Comment: OK, quando um dado já esta inserido ( ... Na Tabela PESSOAS fiz num tipo de insert pois as pessoas já estavam cadastradas, ...) o que você faz é um update para atualizar o campo, você precisa pega o PES_NUMERO, mas como vai usar isso e qual informação você tem para regasta esse número?

Comment: Editei o post com duas imagens, que deve transparecer melhor o que preciso.

Comment: De onde está vindo os dados de uma planilha, do banco de dados ou aplicação.  Mostre como fez os outros insert e o que é preciso fazer,  eu ainda não sei o que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de um relacionamento restritivo entre as tabelas, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
    SELECT pessoa.*, credencial.*
      FROM pessoa
INNER JOIN pessoa_credencial ON pessoa_credencial.id_pessoa = pessoa.id
INNER JOIN credencial ON credencial.id = pessoa_credencial.id_credencial
```

Lembrando que o relacionamento desta forma, caso seu banco de dados possua mais de uma credencial para a mesma pessoa ou mais de uma pessoa para uma credencial) poderá retornar mais de uma linha.

Obs.: O select que montei é um exemplo, não necessariamente representa a estrutura das suas tabelas, mas indica a forma correta de fazer o relacionamento entre as 3 tabelas que você possui.